# Synthesize a BOOL to set value in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean

I have created a BOOL attribute in my Core Data entity called "useSystem". Additionally in order for me to get/set the data I have created an object, however whenever I try to set the synthesized BOOL I get a bus error. This is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic) const BOOL useSystem;
```

So I'm doing

```
[object setUseSystem:YES];
```

And immediately I get the bus error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better style to use NSNumber as the property type actually. This is also what happens when you use the model editor in xcode to add a boolean attribute to an entity. There is 'auto-boxing' going on but I always seem to have less troubles when I just use the higher level Objective-C types and wrappers like NSNumber.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you declare the method explicitly but it might not work with @synthesize. Seems like I've done this before, but maybe I just used the BOOL with no mutator method. (You can use @property without @synthesize if you define the method(s) that @property declares.)